# PHP all full-uppercase words to lowercase

Tags: php, string

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum DOLOR Sit amet";
...some magic here... -> $finalString
$finalString = "Lorem ipsum dolor Sit amet"
```

Basically I wan't to convert all words that are fully uppercase to full lowercase.

Comment: Have you researched this a little? Could be done by exploding the whitespaces and then checking every element or (what I'd prefer) a regex. Try it for yourself and then elaborate on where you failed and why you can't accomplish this by yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sans regex solution...

```
<?php
$string = "Lorem ipsum DOLOR Sit amet";
$str_arr = explode(' ',$string);
foreach($str_arr as &$val)
{
if($val==strtoupper($val))
{
$val=strtolower($val);
}
}
echo $str= implode(' ',$str_arr); //"prints" Lorem ipsum dolor Sit amet
```

Comment: This one only worked for me, I would just suggest modification: `strtoupper($s)`->`mb_strtoupper($s,'utf-8')`. The same with `strtolower`

Answer (score 6):

This is what I suggested initially:

```
$finalString = preg_replace("/\\b[A-Z]+\\b/e", "strtolower(\"\\0\");", $string);
```

But, since PHP 5.5.0 onwards, the `e` modifier in [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) has become deprecated. So the correct alternative would be [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum DOLOR Sit amet";
$finalString = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\\b[A-Z]+\\b/",
    function($matches){
    return strtolower($matches[0]);
    },
    $string
);
```

Comment: `e` modifier is depricated, no ?

Comment: preg_replace_callback() might be a better approach

Comment: Thank you. But there is still something wrong in that regex because this `Aá` becomes `aá` instead of leaving it as `Aá`

Answer (score 2):

[`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) is what you need.

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum DOLOR Sit amet";

$finalString = preg_replace_callback('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', function($m) {
        return strtolower($m[1]);
}, $string);

echo $finalString;
```

`$m[1]` matches the first capturing group `([A-Z]+)` which matches uppercase words. `\b` represent word boundaries.

Comment: Thank you. But there is still something wrong in that regex because this `Aá` becomes `aá` instead of leaving it as `Aá`, same as the answer above you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) with expression `/\b[A-Z]+\b/` (`\b` - start or end of word, `[A-Z]+` - all charactes are uppercased and there is at least one character):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$string = 'Lorem ipsum DOLOR Sit amet';

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\b[A-Z]+\b/',
    function($matches){
        return strtolower($matches[0]);
    },
    $string
);

echo $result;
?>
```

Shows:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor Sit amet
```

***P.S.:*** You may also update regex to lowercase only words, where at least 2 characters by:

```
/\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is still something wrong in that regex because this `Aá` becomes `aá` instead of leaving it as `Aá`, same as the answer above you.